# Lowercase columns names of dataframes inside list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have multiple csv, so I've used glob and read_csv, append each one inside a list then did concatenated all of them.

My question is how can I access to the columns names and lowercase them ?

EDIT:

```
    allfiles = glob.glob("*.csv", )
    dataframes = []
    for file in allfiles :
        dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", decimal=","))
    df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

---

```
allfiles = glob.glob("*.csv", )
dataframes = []
for file in allfiles :
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", decimal=",")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
    dataframes.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Comment: I can't do that, I will share my code just a moment

Answer (score 1):

To rename the columns, you can use the `rename()` [method of DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

Here's an example:

```
df.rename(columns={colname:colname.lower() for colname in df.axes[1]})
```

This uses a list of column names (`df.axes[1]`) to create a `dict` mapping old column names to their new, lower-cased versions. The `rename()` method then returns a copy of the dataframe with the renamed columns.

Note that `rename()` has an `inplace` flag if you'd prefer to edit the dataframe in place rather than return a copy.